# Avoid data race in goroutine inside range with interface

Tags: go

I have following `for...range` block which call the urls using `goroutine`.

```
func callUrls(urls []string, reqBody interface{}) []*Response {
    ch := make(chan *Response, len(urls))
    for _, url := range urls {
        somePostData := reqBody //this just seems to copy reference, not a deep copy
        go func(url string, somePostData interface{}) {
            //serviceMutex.Lock()
            //defer serviceMutex.Unlock()
            somePostData.(map[string]interface{})["someKey"] = "someval" //can be more deeper nested
            //Data race - while executing above line it seems the original data is only getting modified, not the new local variable

            //http post on url,
            postJsonBody, _ := json.Marshal(somePostData)
            req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(postJsonBody))
            req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            req.Header.Set("Connection", "Keep-Alive")

            client := &http.Client{
                Timeout: time.Duration(time.Duration(300) * time.MilliSecond),
            }

            response, err := client.Do(req)
            response.Body.Close()


            // return to channel accordingly
            ch <- &Response{200, "url", "response body"}

        }(url, somePostData)
    }
    //for block to return result.
}
```

Each `goroutine func` needs to post modified post data to url.

However running with `-race` shows data race at the line where post data interface is modified.

I also tried the `sync.Mutex` `Lock()` and `Unlock()` but it seems it blocking the whole app. I don't want to use []bytes so as modifying the slices seems to more cpu consuming(As it seems to me).

What would be best way to avoid data race here. Also the connection doesn't seems to be reused causing http error as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: The connection isn't being reused because the `http.Client` isn't being reused. You're creating a whole new `Client` for every request. You're correct that the `map` is not being deep copied when you pass it; a map is a pointer internally. However it's hard to say how to do it correctly because the quoted example code is invalid; you cannot pass a `interface{}` or a `map` to `bytes.NewBuffer`. Perhaps if you edit your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it might be answerable.

Comment: Did edited. Missed those line from pasting here.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

**Use the Mutex**

This is the safest and most straightforward.  It looks like the scope of your [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) could be reduced to:

```
serviceMutex.Lock()
somePostData.(map[string]interface{})["someKey"] = "someval" 
postJsonBody, _ := json.Marshal(somePostData)
serviceMutex.Unlock()
```

Which should significantly help with your throughput.

**Have each goroutine build its own `somePostData`**

Depending on your data structure this should allow each goroutine to not share data with any other and give you the safety and speed boost.  Imagine instead of passing an `interface{}` with potentially lots of references itself you pass in a thread-safe method that is able to build a request body:

```
func callUrls(urls []string, buildReqBody func(...params...) interface{})
...


somePostData = buildReqBody(...params...)
```

Comment: Mutex lock doesn't seems to work for me. Can't I use the reqBody to generate the post data in each goroutine like i tried?